# TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined with React js

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

So, I am building a dictionary libray trying to fetch API data using Axios, everything works fine, but sometimes it throws ***"TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
"*** for certain words. What might be the issue? Because when I try to get the meaning of some words it works fine, but for some words, it throws an error. The code is below

```
      function App() {    
    const [mapvalue, setMapValue] = useState([])

        const reqLibrary = () => {
            axios.get(dictionaryapi)
            .then((respone) => {
            setMapValue(respone.data.def[0].tr)
            //console.log(respone.data.def[0].tr[0].mean)
        })
      }

      return (
        </div>
      <button onClick={reqLibrary}> Get Words </button>
      <ul>
        {mapvalue.map((response) => (
          <li> {response.mean[0].text} </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
     )

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do null checks. this will help you.

```
setMapValue(respone?.data?.def?.[0]?.tr)
```

doing null check this way is called `Optional_chaining`

learn more about [Optional_chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I am still getting the same error as before. The API shows meaning for words and throws an error some certain words.

Comment: add null checks for everywhere, here too `response.mean?.[0]?.text`

Comment: I didn't get what do you mean "add null checks for everywhere, here too response.mean?.[0]?.text"? I would really appreciate if you could help me with this issue

Comment: yes wherever you feel value can be null you can use `?.` notation to access